# Postgress Sql Query help to get un matching records from two tables for a given particular day and add a user defined transcation column

Tags: sql, postgresql

All,  want to fetch all insert , update, deleted rows from a 2 tables (Table 1 & table 2) and have their respective archive tables. Table 1 & table2 holds only current day data.  Arch tables hold data for everyday.

Below is sample data. Data might be pretty huge on daily basis.

Table 1 & day 1 data:

```
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | soft_ski_name | soft_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A1            | 989     | 3       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A2            | 97979   |         | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

table 1 - day 2

```
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | soft_ski_name | soft_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A1            | 9897    | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A3            | 97979   | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

table1-arch

```
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | soft_ski_name | soft_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A1            | 9897    | 3       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A2            | 97979   |         | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A1            | 9897    | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A3            | 97979   | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

---

table 2- day 1

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | techname | tech_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | B1       | 3415    |         | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | B2       | 1838    | 2       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

table 2- day 2

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | techname | tech_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | B3       | 6767    | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | B6       | 121     | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | B1       | 3415    | 2       | N          | N        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

table 2-arch

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | techname | tech_id | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | load_dt    |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A3       |         |         | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A5       |         | 2       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/26/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | A3       |         | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 7868    | A6`      |         | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1234    | B1       | 3415    | 2       | N          | N        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | 08/27/2023 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

excepted o/p:

```
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| user_id | soft_ski_name |tech_id   | prof_id | demand_ind | irre_ind | learn_ind | dislike_ind | less_ind | rating_dt         | demand_ind | User_transcation_type |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1234    | A1            | 9897  | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | Update                |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 7868    | A3            | 97979 | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | Add                   |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 7868    | A2            | 97979 |         | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | Delet                 |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1234    | B3            | 6767  | 4       | Y          | Y        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/24/23 01:23:21 | Y          | Add                   |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 7868    | B6            | 121   | 1       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | Add                   |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1234    | B1            | 3415  | 2       | N          | N        | N         | Y           | N        | 08/25/23 01:23:21 | N          | Update                |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 7868    | B2            | 1838  | 2       | N          | N        | N         | N           | Y        | 08/21/23 01:23:21 | N          | Delete                |
+---------+---------------+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: What's wrong with union all for this? e.g. `select col1,col2,col3 from tA union all select col1,col2col3 from tB`  - OR - there is more to this question that you have not yet explained.

Answer (score 0):

follow this

```
-- For Table1
SELECT
user_id,
soft_ski_name,
tech_id,
prof_id,
demand_ind,
irre_ind,
learn_ind,
dislike_ind,
less_ind,
rating_dt,
demand_ind,
'Add' AS user_transaction_type
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table1_arch AS t1a
WHERE t1a.user_id = t1.user_id
  AND t1a.soft_ski_name = t1.soft_ski_name
  AND t1a.tech_id = t1.tech_id
  AND t1a.prof_id = t1.prof_id
  -- Add more conditions as needed
 )
 UNION
SELECT
user_id,
soft_ski_name,
tech_id,
prof_id,
demand_ind,
irre_ind,
learn_ind,
dislike_ind,
less_ind,
rating_dt,
demand_ind,
'Update' AS user_transaction_type
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table1_arch AS t1a ON
t1a.user_id = t1.user_id
AND t1a.soft_ski_name = t1.soft_ski_name
AND t1a.tech_id = t1.tech_id
AND t1a.prof_id = t1.prof_id
-- Add more conditions as needed
WHERE
t1a.demand_ind != t1.demand_ind
-- Add more conditions as needed
UNION
SELECT
user_id,
soft_ski_name,
tech_id,
prof_id,
demand_ind,
irre_ind,
learn_ind,
dislike_ind,
less_ind,
rating_dt,
demand_ind,
'Delete' AS user_transaction_type
FROM table1_arch AS t1a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.user_id = t1a.user_id
  AND t1.soft_ski_name = t1a.soft_ski_name
  AND t1.tech_id = t1a.tech_id
  AND t1.prof_id = t1a.prof_id
  -- Add more conditions as needed
 );

-- Repeat a similar process for Table2
```